# How to make an item Selected from code but disable user to select on CollectionView in .NET 7 MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I am working on a .NET 7 MAUI project and want to change the style of a specific item on CollectionView from C#. Currently it's working but all the other items are also selectable on CollectionView. How can I disable the user from selecting items while still selecting an item from code behind?

This is the code behind that selects an item:

```
SelectedItem = Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSelectedNext);
```

```
<CollectionView
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid
             ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto">
                <Label 
                    VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                Text="{Binding FullName}" />

                <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding Time}"/>

                    <Label
                        Text="{Binding TimePostfix}"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

I tried using CollectionView.SelectionMode="None" but that hides also the selection that is done from c#.
When I try to use CollectionView.SelectionMode="Single" I can see it but also can select other items on CollectionView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you test it on the android? It seems there was a bug on the windows and ios about [CollectionView selection does not display selection when page appearing](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8573). The **SelectedItem** can't be set in the code behind in my project.

In addition, I creae a sample and get the effect you want on the android. You can add some logic code in the **CollectionView's SelectedItemChanged event** to set the SelectedItem as you want. Such as:

```
collectionview.SelectionChanged += (s, e) =>
   {  
       if (collectionview.SelectedItem != Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSelectedNext))
       {
          collectionview.SelectedItem = Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSelectedNext);
       }
   };
```

You can put the following code in the code behind. And if you used the viewmodel. You can use the [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior) to convert this event to a command in the viewmodel.

In addition, I have tried the `InputTransparent="True"` property Arvis mentioned. It will make the collectionview can't be scrolled and seems be disabled.

Comment: He can put the CollectionView in to ScrollView.

Comment: @Arvis this is terrible. One of the worst choices and misuse of lists. While the list itself has mechanism of knowing what to show and what not, the scroll view does not care about it. It all gets loaded at the same time.

Comment: @H.A.H. correct. That's why I call it hackaround (not a choice for large lists or at all).